# Compile errors from winnt.h, winbase.h, and excpt.h for windows mobile project

Tags: c++, windows, mobile

I have desktop project which is compiled successfully, but after I add new configuration to the project to support Windows Mobile platforms, I receive the following errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ContextRecord' winnt.h
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int winnt.h

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LPCONTEXT'   winbase.h
error C2040: 'PCONTEXT' : '_CONTEXT *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'  excpt.h
```

The project does not include winnt.h, but it includes windows.h, windbase.h.  I search on google that I have to change Project properties->configuration properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->definitions to add like _MBCS, or add $(*ARCHFAM*), $(ARCHFAM).  Or change the order of the header files which I have done that too by putting windows.h on the top of other header files, but all not fixing the errors.

Any suggestion that I can fix these? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`#include<windows.h>` out of all 3 of those, windows.h drags them all in. This is the only include you need. it covers 80 percent of all windows api's , minus some specialized discrete aspects of the os (such as direct 2d, encryption, ect)

Comment: I comment ou the windows.h header files from three .cpp files which is all I can find by using CTR-F, but the same amount of errors are still there.

Comment: I meant I comment out those three windows.h files.

Comment: it is kind hard to post the code because project has over 18 .cpp files and the codes are for internally used only.

Comment: Does the project have a stadfx and is that header included in all theh cpp files? if so THATS where you need to put your #include<windows.h>

Comment: you can also compile with \ShowIncludes and the compiler will emit which headers are included when.. it'll give you a rough overview of where the issue is

Comment: Also, use #pragma once at the top of all your header files. it's effectively the same as putting include guards on them.

Answer (score 2):

I got these errors too. My problem was that I forgot a ";" behind my class defintion in one of my header files.

Instead of:

```
class myClass
{
   ...
};
```

I had:

```
class myClass
{
    ...
}
```

Maybe it helps someone...

Comment: Yes! Was getting an unknown type/var for `WCHAR` which is defined in winnt.h.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to correct manually a syntactic mistake in a file winnt.h

Line:           typedef void *POINTER_64 PVOID64;

We correct:     typedef void *POINTER_64, *PVOID64;

Or on two:      typedef void *POINTER_64;
                typedef void *PVOID64;

Errors disappear

Answer (score 0):

I had windows.h in my dll header file.
Moved it out of the header file and into only the .cpp projects that require windows.h in and it worked.

The console test app for the DLL got mad when it tried to include a bunch of windows stuff.